# complex aggregate in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Item(models.model):
    price = models.floatField()
    ...
```

and :

```
class purchase(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date = models.DateField()
```

I would like to make a query which will provide top 10 users who purchased the most in the last week .I would also like to have the Sum of the purchased they completed in that week.

So the output I would like to show on my page is similar to this :

Top buyers of the week :

```
1. User_1   |  150 Points
2. User_2   |  130 Points
...
10. User_10 |  10 Points
```

Is it possible to use annotate for that ? or it should be break ot several queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's give it a go (still needs to be tested for optimized SQL):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


some_day_last_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)

rows = User.objects.filter(purchases__date__gte=some_day_last_week)\
                   .annotate(item_sum=Sum('purchases__item__price'))\
                   .order_by('item_sum')[:10]

print [(u.username, u.item_sum) for u in rows]
```

Comment: I think you meant pruchase__date__get instead of purchases_date__gte ? you used it twice also in the Sum part "Sum('purchase"s"__item__price). Am I correct ?

Comment: Changing to purchase instead of purchases and it worked. Also needed to change the .order_by('item_sum') to .order_by('-item_sum'). But worked like a charm :) I was not sure that the filter and annotate will really adds up here. Because you filter the user object I thiought doing so will result with users who made a purchase in the last week and not all purchases.. still not quite sure why it works :)

Comment: @Nuno_147 I've used `related_name='purchases'` for `Purchase.user` field. With `order_by` you're right, my bad ;)